# Recycler view with Firebase data only loads when scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with `Firebase` and using a `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. The issue is that `onStart` the view loads empty and the data is filled only after scrolling. Any idea why ?

**Code** :

**RecyclerView** (I am setting an empty adapter onStart to avoid "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" ) :

```
 mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
 mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

 mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(1,0);                                     
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

**Firebase data fetch:**

```
databaseReference.child("/News").orderByChild("createdAt").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            final News news = postSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
            final PostListClass postListClass = new PostListClass();
            //add fac id admin
            if (news.getFaculteId().equals(userFaculteId) || news.getFaculteId().equals("Admin")) {
                postListClass.setPostId(postSnapshot.getKey());
                postListClass.setPostTitle(news.getHeadlines());
                postListClass.setPostDescription(news.getDetails());

                databaseReference.child("/users").child(news.getAuthor()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot usersSnapShot) {
                        User user = usersSnapShot.getValue(User.class);

                        postListClass.setPostOwnerId(usersSnapShot.getKey());
                        postListClass.setPostOwnerName(user.getPrenom() + " " + user.getNom());
                        postListClass.setPostOwnerPromo(user.getPromotion());

                        try {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            cal.setTimeInMillis(news.getCreatedAt() * 1000);
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                            Date date = sdf.parse(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString());
                            String day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date);
                            String month = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", date);
                            postListClass.setPostDate(day + " " + month);
                        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        storageRef.child("users/" + news.getAuthor() + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                postListClass.setPostOwnerImageUrl(String.valueOf(uri));
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                // Handle any errors

                                if (exception.getClass().isInstance(StorageException.class)) {
                                    postListClass.setPostOwnerImageUrl("NullImage");

                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });

                databaseReference.child("/News").child(postSnapshot.getKey()).child("/Comments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        postListClass.setPostComments(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                storageRef.child("News/" + postSnapshot.getKey() + ".png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        postListClass.setPostImageUrl(String.valueOf(uri));

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                        postListClass.setPostImageUrl("NullImage");

                    }
                });

                postListClasses.add(postListClass);


            }

        }

       postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(getContext(), postListClasses);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**So this is the result when the app starts (Three fields are missing data) :**

[image]

**And After Scrolling (Missing data gets filled) :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. So when you attach the adapter to the list, there is not data yet.

Once data comes in from the server, you need to alert the list of that. You do this by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just added `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, still the same issue. The thing is the title and content are loaded, but the data from the second Firebase data fetch are not loaded until i scroll the recycler view.

Comment: They likely *are* loaded, but just not shown. In general this involves informing the adapter (and from there the view) that the data has changed.

Comment: My bad, i ended up adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the second fetch and it worked, thank you.

Comment: You got pretty far, so this is just the final step. Unfortunately it's an easy one to forget or to simply not know about. Good to hear you got it working!